# Why does UIDimmingView always cover screen main bounds?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to make bottom slider menu containing a table view controller and a search controller inside of table view header. At this point, I added table view controller as a child view controller. After search bar is focused dimming view triggers but it covers screen main bound. What I expect is that dimming view stays inside the child view controller boundaries. I could not understand the reason why dimming view always added screen main bounds ? I have a screen shot to demonstrate the issue I have.

Thanks for your help.

```
class ChildTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let temp = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultSearchController)
        temp.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
        return temp
    }()

    private var resultSearchController = ResultSearchTableViewController(style: .plain)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        prepareViewController()
    }

    func prepareViewController() {
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .singleLine
        self.tableView.register(ChildTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ChildTableViewCell.identifier)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        self.definesPresentationContext = true
    }

}
```

[Screen shot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aLTg04DZGMukMnuVW217wYKWCKs69MX2/view)

Comment: How do you know its `UIDimmingView`? I can't understand it is that from the code you posted here, do you have any other code to look at that can help more?

Comment: Hi, I edited the screen shot. You can believe me, it's a UIDimmingView :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if its content appears over a child view controller context, the search controller itself is a presented view controller and prevents interaction with any other interface. Thus it makes sense that if you ask for the dimming view, the dimming view covers everything other than the search controller interface. If you don't like that, set `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` to `false`.

(You should not be using `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation`. Use `obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation` instead.)

Comment: So, you'are saying that wherever I put search control, dimmingView covers all the presented view controllers on the screen.